# Is there a way to make systemd service shutdown the system when it (the service) stops?

Tags: linux, systemd

I have few Linux boxes each running a service. This is the only important process running on these machines. However, sometimes due to some internal state-changes in the service, it will gracefully stop itself. What I am looking for is an idiomatic way to shutdown the whole system when this happens. Basically I want the systemd to halt the system when `myservice` service is no longer running.

Is there an easy way to do this?

What I do at the moment is that I have developed another service `myservice-monitor` which monitors the `myservice` and when it stops, then `myservice-monitor` shutdowns the system. It all works, but I thought there must be a way to solve this in a more idiomatic approach...

Comment: Does your service return the status like "stopped" or "OK" or something? If yes, just write a script to check for the status and shutdown the system if the response is "stopped". Use a root crontab for the periodical check and off you go.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I already have a service that exactly what the crontab job does in your proposal... I thought it is possible to be done by systemd itself. I need to read systemd docs...

Comment: If the service is under your direct control, you could also initiate the shutdown from inside the service itself.

Comment: Can you point me in the right direction please (@ systemd documentation) ? I can't find it how to do it...

Comment: Sorry I meant that if you wrote your service yourself, you can program a shutdown on clean exit _into_ the service, maybe. EDIT: Have a look at this maybe: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/systemd-halt.service.8.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do this with `systemd`, although I don't know how advisable it is. If the service crashes or needs to be restarted during an upgrade, the machine will shutdown in those cases, too!

You can add this to your `systemd` unit file file for your service:

```
 ExecStopPost=/sbin/halt
```

See `man systemd.service` for the full docs and disclaimers about `ExecStopPost`.

Comment: Excellent! I think this is it. I actually DO want the machine to be shut down (in fact I want it `terminated` in AWS parlance) because if I want more instances of that service to run again, I will run more new machines.

Comment: I certainly will, once I test it.

Comment: I end up using this pattern myself. It "works for me".